# What happens to Strings when object is cloned in Java?

Tags: java, string, jvm, cloning, shallow-copy

By default Java does Shallow Cloning, if an object is cloned and it has a String like this `String s = new String("Hi");` then the cloned object will point to a new String object or it will have a reference to the previous object?

The question here is that does Java treat Strings different when cloning and creates a new object of it or not??

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific about your terminology. "Shallow cloning" is like an oxymoron because a "shallow copy" and a "clone" are opposites. And the word clone in Java is also used to describe the `clone()` method (which should generally be avoided). Regarding `new String()`, the `new` keyword *always* gives you a newly allocated object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### new always creates new String object

1. Every time `new` is used to create a String, it will create a new object
2. The references pointing to Strings created by `new` can be `intern`ed to assign to an existing entry in String pool or creates new entry if it does not exist.

### clone

1. In case of clone, it all depends on the implementation of clone method
2. If the clone is done as `super.clone` without any additional code, then all the references are copied (assuming `super` is Object)
3. So the `String` references inside the cloned object will share the existing `String` objects pointed by original object